# What tools do I need installed on Unix to let C programs access an Informix database installed on Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, informix

I have C applications that have been running on HP-UX B.11 and Informix Dynamic Server Version 7.31.UD1 for years.  I have migrated the database to the earliest Informix (V.14.2) on CentOS 7.
What are the best tools I need to use so I can continue to run the programs on Unix and access the Informix database on Linux?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a version 14.2 of Informix. There are versions 14.10.FCn where n is a smallish number.

Comment: You are right. We have installed IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC7DE on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear whether you are seeking to run programs on the HP-UX box and connect to the database server on the Linux box, or whether you are seeking to migrate the programs from the HP-UX box to the Linux box.

##### Running the programs on HP-UX still

As long as you can change the setting of the `$INFORMIXSERVER` environment variable and modify the `$INFORMIXSQLHOSTS` file (usually `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts`) to point to the new server on the Linux machine, the tools running on HP-UX box will continue to work — you don't need to install anything new there.  If any of the tools have been hardwired with connection information, you may have to work a bit harder, but it should still be doable.  You might have to set up a server alias for the new server that matches what was used on the HP-UX box

Any programs trying to run the server administration tools (`oncheck`, `ontape`, `onparams`, `onspaces`, `onstat`, etc.) will need to be run on the Linux server machine.

#### Running the programs on Linux instead

You will need to port the code for the existing applications from HP-UX to Linux.  That means recompiling unless the programs are all Java.  You need to know what APIs are in use — the process may be more contorted for ODBC than for ESQL/C, or vice versa (it depends on how well written the programs are).
If you use Java, then you'll need Informix JDBC and at least the JRE (you'll need the JDK if you need to compile the Java programs again).  If you use ODBC or ESQL/C, you'll need the Informix ClientSDK, a C compiler and the general development tools (`make`, etc). If you use I4GL, you'll need Informix 4GL on the Linux platform too.

Comment: I am seeking to run programs on the HP-UX box and connect to the database server on the Linux box. I want to keep the programs on Unix  they can't compile on Linux due to the fact that they are more than 20 years old.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for your help.  One other question about how to refer to Linux box in the sqlhosts file.

Comment: rsi_shm     onipcshm        taxtest        rsishm
rsi_tcp       onsoctcp        taxtest        rsitcp                                          These are the entries we currently have in the sqlhosts file in Unix. How do I refer to  rsi_shm (informix server name)  in Linux in the file?   Thanks for your precious help

Comment: You'll have set the Linux database server up with network connections — `olsoctcp`.  On the Unix box, you'll have a line like `informixserver oltlitcp linux-hostname port-no` and you'll set `INFORMIXSERVER=informixserver` in your environment.  Now attempts to connect to `database@informixserver` (or just `database`) will attempt to connect over the network to the instance running on `linux-hostname` that is listening to the port number `port-no` (or you can use a service name if you prefer; you have to set up `/etc/services` to use the same name for the service on both machines).

Comment: Be aware that you cannot use shared memory connections between different machines.  You must use the `onsoctcp` (aka `olsoctcp`) connection type.  You can create an alias `rsi_shm` (in `DBSERVERALIASES` in `$ONCONFIG`) on the Linux box using `olsoctcp` as the connection type.  You then have `rsi_shm onsoctcp linux-hostname port-no` on the HP-UX box to connect to Linux. Right now, while experimenting and getting things running, you can set `INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=/some/spare/location/sqlhosts` in the environment so you don't mess up the main `sqlhosts` file until you're confident the new stuff works.

Comment: Thank You Jonathan, I will try it and give some feedback.

Comment: Ted, with reference to your comment "I want to keep the programs on Unix they can't compile on Linux due to the fact that they are more than 20 years old".  If given that you were using an Informix database, that these C-applications were Informix 4gl applications compiled as C via the c4gl compiler, there are options available to you to recompile those applications.